# Date and time library with period support for C#/VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am looking for a library doing set operations on time periods with support of weekdays and time of day. I have started to roll my own, but it seems like a error-prone job so I would like a tested solution for this. I don't mind spending money.

If I have a set of two time periods (this can be several)

Setup:

```
// [period 1]:
TimeSet.Add(1 January 2008-31 January 2008 every Tuesday 14:00-15:00) 
// [period 2]
TimeSet.AddWithOr(1 January 2008-15 January 2008 every Tuesday 13:00-14:00)
```

Results:

```
TimeSet.ContainsTime(2 January 2008 13:45) = False
TimeSet.ContainsTime(2 January 2008 14:15) = True // [period 1]
TimeSet.ContainsTime(2 January 2008 13:15) = True // [period 2]
```

I also need range checking functions:

```
// Only Tuesday 13-15 is in range:
TimeSet.ContainsTime(24 December 2007 13:45,1 January 2008 13:00) = False
TimeSet.ContainsTime(24 December 2007 13:45,2 January 2008 12:59) = False 
TimeSet.ContainsTime(24 December 2007 13:45,2 January 2008 13:00) = True
```

Other more advanced set functions is a plus.

I tried googling for it, but was unable to find anything.

Comment: Maybe some 3rd party sheduling/calendar controls have such functionality...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/datetime/TimePeriod.aspx

Comment: I haven't tested the library, but it seems this library has the functionality I was after. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any that exist as a C#/.NET framework however you may be able to adapt the [Quartz project's](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) (a C# scheduler) calendar namespace. This includes a [`CronCalendar`](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/apidoc/) object. I haven't used [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) for a while but I can remember it supports the kind of occurrence system you're after.

There's [quite a few helper extensions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/index.aspx#Date) you could use on codeproject, like a [AddBusinessDay](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/AddBusinessDay.aspx) method which may also help out.

In terms of parsing what you have for the format - you may want to change this to a fluent interface to make development/testing quicker and save having to write a complicated token parsing class. You could just keep it in Cron format to make the Quartz code even easier to integrate, unless it's being used by none-techies.

Comment: The Quartz classes looks promising, as for parsing the dates are stored in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the versatile [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members(printer).aspx) structure. It has 
operators for comparing two DateTime's, e.g. LessThan. Thus 
the set operations and the range checking functions are 
fairly trivial to implement in a simple class for this 
purpose.

The central data structure in such a class could be a list 
of DateTime ranges sorted by start time. If a new DateTime 
range is added then it is merged with an existing DateTime 
range if there is any overlap. If it is merged with one of 
them a run through the new list is required to see if any 
DateTime range now overlap (and then a merge is required). 
This is repeated until there are no more overlaps.

Comment: I have created my own (using DateTime). If I split each period definition into several "DateRanges" I end up with a lot of ranges - 365-366 ranges for 1 Jan-31 Dec 14:00-15:00.

Comment: OK, I see. This is not an efficient representation then, but it should still work. Could it be a floating point rounding problem? E.g. 14.00 may not be the same as 13.00 + 1 hour. –

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28printer%29.aspx) Structure

Comment: How would TimeSpan structure help me?